# Did I set the mimetype wrong? or what do I need to do in order to successfully send the email

Tags: php, html, css, web-development-server

I'm trying to play around with php, since I'm relatively new to it. I was wondering what do I need to do in order to successfully send an email when the user fills out all the required fields (not shown in this example. Basically if I fill in the fields for "first and last names", "phone number, email, and the message fields" I'm trying to actually send a nice formatted email using html and css to the client (the person whoever is getting the email) But in this case I'm sending the entire html syntax to the user instead of actually sending the "text" that was typed by the user.

```
 $email_content =
                "
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>$subject</title>
                <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
                <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\">
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.iconmonstr.com/1.3.0/css/iconmonstr-iconic-font.min.css\">
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/bootstrap-grid.css\"> 
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css\" integrity=\"sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div class=\"container\">
                        <div class=\"row\">
                            <div class=\"col-12 text-center\">
                            <a href=\"https://www.snizzyDragonsTest.com/\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"btn btn-primary ml-auto\">Visit Website </a>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div class=\"col-12 green-color-bg\">


                                <p class=\"text-head\" style=\"font-family: 'Niconne'; \"> snizzyDragonsTest</p>

                            </div>
                            <div class=\"col-12 white-color-bg text-center\">
                                <p class=\"text-head-email green-text greys-color-bg \" style=\"font-family: 'Roboto';  \" >Name:<span style =\"color: #555;\">$first $last</span></p>
                                <p class=\"text-head-email green-text greys-color-bg \" style=\"font-family: 'Roboto';  \" >Email: <span style =\"color: #555;\">$email</span></p>
                                <p class=\"text-head-email green-text greys-color-bg \" style=\"font-family: 'Roboto';  \" >Phone: <span style =\"color: #555;\">$phone</span></p>
                                <p class=\"text-head-email green-text greys-color-bg \" style=\"font-family: 'Roboto';  \" >Inquiring About: <span style =\"color: #555;\">$products</span></p>
                                <p class=\"text-head-email green-text greys-color-bg \" style=\"font-family: 'Roboto';  \" >Message: <span style =\"color: #555;\">$message</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class =\"col-12 green-color-bg\">

                            <div class=\"footer-copyright text-center  py-3\">snizzyDragonsTest &copy;2018 Copyright. All rights reserved.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
                ";







    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $email_headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $email_headers .= 'From: $first $last  <$email>' . "\r\n";



    // Send the email.
    mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);
```

**OUTPUT(expected output)**
[image]

**OUTPUT(ACTUAL OUTPUT)**
[image]

Comment: Are email headers case-sensitive? You wrote "Content-type", but it should be "Content-Type".

Comment: Uhm I tried it, but this time i get no styling and no images which is weird, I dont think its ever accessing the images, and css, because its stored in my computer and not out there online, would that be correct ?

Comment: Correct. You can't use relative URLs for your resources in an email, because there's no root the way there would be in a webpage accessed from a browser. You need to use full, absolute URL paths.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, so do i go something like https://www.snizzyDragonsTest.com/css/styles.css ? like I want to specifically  use my css/html/js files

Comment: If your server is hosted at that URL, yes; be sure to include the protocol as well (`http://` or `https://` usually).

Comment: okay i have done that and updated it, but I don't see any results, I assume it will take the  server sometime for it to be updated, because i closed deleted my history(so i can get rid of the cache) and hope to see for an update, but nothing new. So in this case I shall just wait for the server to be updated right @IceMetalPunk

Comment: No? Invalid URLs don't get cached, and even if they did, clearing your cache would cause the next request to be the new content immediately. Are you sure you've entered the URL to your images and style sheets correctly? (FYI, snizzydragonstest.com doesn't actually exist; I'm not sure if you just meant that as an example, not the actual URL, but don't use it as the URL because it's not real.)